# In which SOAP test suite can we add conditional elements like if and use injected values?

Tags: testing, soap, soapui

I have a business file which contains a structure similar to SOAP message. It contains Envelope, Header and Body elements however there are also some unknown elements as:

```
<#if IF ${CarMake='VOLVO'}>
  <bounty>18000</bounty>
</#if>
```

Could you please suggest where does this syntax come from? Is it some kind of SoapUI test case configuration file?

Comment: It doesn't look like XSLT (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_if.asp). Perhaps it is a colloquial format that your business uses?

Comment: Could be the Freemarker templating language.